# How to load View in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to load a (M **V** C) View in an iframe. But the view which i am trying to load in an iframe does not contain any action , i added it manually. For clearity suppose

```
 Index.cshtl => View

 public ActionResult Index() => Action of index view
 {
  return View()
 }                          This view loads perfectly in iframe
```

Now

```
 Test.cshtml => View

 No action for this view   & I want to load this view in iframe.
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Why you need the 'view' inside an iframe? please put a full example of what you wish to do in jsFiddle or jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , we just have to send the requet to the **`Action`** from where the **`Test view`** is called like :

```
  <iframe src="/controllername/actionname?viewname"></iframe>
```

this setup is in my case may be in your case it is different. I hope it helps.